# BigQuery : File format of the exported CSV files (when multiple files)

Tags: export, google-bigquery

When exporting a Big Query table , csv format, if the export is bigger than 1GB it will be divided into multiple files ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files)).

I'm trying to find out if all the files will have a header or just the first one (without exporting more than 1GB indeed).

Comment: Just checked here on our exported files and they all contain a header.

Comment: thanks, that was my hope. You can add this as a real answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked here on our exports and all files do contain a header. Looking the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#configuring_export_options) it doesn't seem like it's possible to change that.